# TFS 2013 Multipipeline builds like in Jenkins

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2013

I have been looking for a while now. Is there any way to create something like multipipeline branches from jenkins in TFS 2013?

Multipipeline builds in Jenkins work such that everytime a developer creates a branch in the repository, Jenkins would clone the main build and create a new build specifically for that new branch. Once the branch is deleted, the build also disappears. This way we can make sure that nothing is merged back to master, that did not pass tests or doesn't build.

Is there any way to achieve the same effect in TFS 2013? I know its possible in Azure DevOps but can't find anything specifically on TFS 2013. Sadly TFS2013 is a constraint of the project and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to achieve the same effect in TFS 2013?

I am afraid there is no same workflow in TFS2013, TFS newer versions(e.g. 2015 2017 2018...),Azure Devops Service.

Since TFS2013 is an older version, many features are not supported in this version of TFS.

For example: [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops), [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic&viewFallbackFrom=tfs-2015) and so on.

So even a similar workflow cannot be used in TFS2013. I suggest you can update TFS2013 to a newer version, so you will have more applicable functions

In the newer version of TFS, Azure Devops Server or Azure Devops Service, it can use **triggers** and **conditions** to trigger build or task to verify the branch.

For example:

You could set CI Trigger for pipeline, and set condition for some tasks. Then when the new branch is created, it will trigger the build.  In the build, it will determine the task to run based on the triggered branch（condition).

Or in order to avoid directly merging the branch into the master, you can use PR trigger to pre-merge the branch so that you can verify that the branch is correct.

For more detailed information, you could refer to this doc: [Build multiple branches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=tfs-2017&tabs=classic)